# "Fatal error: Index out of range 2019-08-30 11:01:35.001667-0400 fmcBeta[58563:3478851] Fatal error: Index out of range"

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

[image][image: Line where err happens]I am creating an events feed, using a table view and Firebase as my database. I am using dateformatter with a style type of full for date and short for time and writing it to my database as a string which is perfect, it writes exactly how i want it to.

However, when i try to read the data from firebase and display it on my textlabel in the tableview cell i get the following error.

**Error:**

> "Fatal error: Index out of range
>   2019-08-30 11:01:35.001667-0400 fmcBeta[58563:3478851] Fatal error: Index out of range"

Any help would be greatly appreciated i am self learning and fairly new to swift.

**This is my table view cell:**

```swift
class EventsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var eventLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventTitle: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**This is my viewcontoller with tableview protocols:**

```swift
class EventsViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var eventsRef: DatabaseReference?
    var eventsDatabaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?


    var eventsTitles = [String]()
    var eventTimestamps:[String] = []
    var eventsLocations = [String]()
      eventsRef = Database.database().reference()

        tableView.reloadData()

  tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    eventsDatabaseHandle = eventsRef?.child("Church Events").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snaphot) in

         let eventPost = snaphot.value as! [String: Any]


       self.eventTimestamps.append(eventPost["eventdate"] as! String)


        self.eventsTitles.append(eventPost["eventtitle"] as! String)

self.eventsLocations.append(eventPost["eventlocation"] as! String)


        self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventsTitles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "events") as! EventsTableViewCell

        cell.eventTitle.text! = eventsTitles[indexPath.row]

        cell.eventDate.text! =  eventTimestamps[indexPath.row]

        cell.eventLocation.text! = eventsLocations[indexPath.row]


        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)



        return cell
    }

}
```

**This is how i'm writing the data to Firebase**

```swift
 @IBAction func saveEventsButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let eventsDates = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: eventDateSelector.date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.full, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short) as String

        print(eventsDates.description)

        let eventSaved:[String: Any] = ["eventdate": eventsDates,"eventtitle":eventsTitleTextField.text!,"eventlocation":eventsLocation.text!]

        eventsRef.child("Church Events").childByAutoId().setValue(eventSaved)

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

[image: Screen Shot of string in database]

Comment: You hold dates as a string?

Comment: My thinking behind it was i wanted to post the exact date and time from the date picker to my server not as a time stamp because i wanted to read it exactly how it was posted so that the event dates could be accurate when the users post it. i thought it would simplify things. if that makes sense

Comment: If it just for logging then no problem however it's of no use for anything now as you cannot compare it for example without extensive parsing code to get it back to a proper date object.

Comment: I have an observer that suppose to take a snapshot of the church events node and i have pointed it to the child node eventdate which has the date as a string. there no way to read that string and append it to a uilabel ?

Comment: What exact line does the error come from?

Comment: i'll post an image @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen can you see my image post, happens right here "cell.eventDate.text! =  eventTimestamps[indexPath.row]"

Comment: Point: Your code is very unsafe.
Obviously you will face this issue. Timestamp always saved in Number format i.e. Double and you are directly displaying on the label as String.

Comment: The error in the screenshot is different from the one you posted as text. There is no way the error you posted as text can be thrown by the line in the screen as far as I can see. I recommend simplifying the problem by restarting from scratch and limiting the data and code to its minimum. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're right @FrankvanPuffelen its throwing a different error now.

Comment: I figured it out, it was my fault i had a line of code cancelled out when troubleshooting a previous error. it was this one -> "self.eventTimestamps.append(eventPost["eventdate"] as! String)"